# Rectangle Area Calculation Function Problem

Tags: python, function

I tried a very simple function to calculate the rectangle area, but it doesn't work, it doesn't even get the input, anyone can see my code and let me know what is my problem in this code, please, and thank you?

```
def get_input(a,b):
    a = int(input("Please enter the width: \n"))
    b = int(input("Please enter the length: \n"))

def show_area(c):
    print("The area of the rectangle is: {c}".format(c))
    
def calculate_area(a,b):
    get_input(a,b)
    c=a*b
    show_area(c)    
    
calculate_area(a,b)
```

Comment: You are passing a and b *into* get_input as arguments. You should be returning them *from* get_input.

Comment: Please specify what "doesn't work" means. The code you have provided will throw a `NameError` because `a` and `b` are undefined the first time you use them in `calculate_area(a, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is scope; you're using the variables `a` and `b` but when you assign values to them within a function, because you haven't declared them `global`, the assignment won't affect anything outside of that function. It also seems like you've declared `a` and `b` above somewhere, considering that you're executing `calculate_area(a,b)` but haven't actually declared `a` or `b` in that scope in your example.

You also seem to think that if you pass in `a` and `b` as arguments to `get_input`, that they will be affected in the original function. That's not how variables work in Python. If you pass an *object*, you can alter *properties* of that object when you pass the object to a function, but if you tried to change *which* object the variable was pointing to, that would only work if you declared a `global`.

All you have to do is remove `a` and `b` from the arguments of your functions, and instead, *return* them from `get_input`. Also, using f-strings makes the printing simpler:

```
def get_input(): # No need to pass in a and b; we're creating them here
    a = int(input("Please enter the width: \n"))
    b = int(input("Please enter the length: \n"))
    return a, b # return a tuple of (a, b)


def show_area(c):
    print(f"The area of the rectangle is: {c}") #f-strings are more straightforward


def calculate_area(): #no need to pass in a and b; they're created in the middle of this function
    a, b = get_input() # you can assign multiple variables at once if the function returns a tuple
    c = a * b
    show_area(c)


calculate_area() # there is no a or b declared in this scope so no need to pass them in
```

If you had used globals instead, your code could look like this - you don't need to return anything, but you do have to declare `a` and `b` as globals if you want their value to change outside of the function:

```
# a and b must be defined within the module scope in order to use them within functions
a = 0
b = 0


def get_input():
    global a
    global b
    a = int(input("Please enter the width: \n"))
    b = int(input("Please enter the length: \n"))


def show_area(c):
    print(f"The area of the rectangle is: {c}")


def calculate_area():
    get_input()
    c = a * b
    show_area(c)


calculate_area()
```

Lastly, you could use a class to store a and b, so that you don't have to declare them as globals:

```
class AreaCalculator:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):  # default a and b to zero
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def get_input(self):
        self.a = int(input("Please enter the width: \n"))
        self.b = int(input("Please enter the length: \n"))

    @staticmethod  # this method is declared as "static" because it doesn't use any "self" variables
    def show_area(c):
        print(f"The area of the rectangle is: {c}")

    def calculate_area(self):
        self.get_input()
        c = self.a * self.b
        self.show_area(c)


ac = AreaCalculator()
ac.calculate_area()
```

Comment: oh right, thank you. How can I fix it? if I add global inside the function get_input() it still doesn't recognize it on called function calculate_area(a,b).

Comment: @RozitaGhasemi I added an example of how to solve it with globals and without them

Comment: @RozitaGhasemi I added another example, this one is about how to use a Class to do the same thing. All code I've shared has identical output. Hopefully you can use my examples to understand the nuances and differences that I've pointed out.